# Compute $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-y}y^a\mathrm{d} y$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Does the following integral have a finite value? How to compute it?
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^k}\mathrm{d} x$$
where $k$ is given and $0<k<1$. By substituting $x^k=y$ we may obtain an equivalent integral
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-y}y^a\mathrm{d} y$$
where $a>0$ is given.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: That looks like a [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: @Tunococ: 11 seconds :)

Comment: Existence does not require knowing about the Gamma function. Our integrand behaves nicely near $0$, and in the long run decays (far) more rapidly than $1/x^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I got your meaning that once the integrand decays faster than $1/x^2$ and then the integral has a finite value.  Is it correct in the long run the integrand decays more rapidly than any $1/x^k$ with $k>0$?

Comment: @Shiyu: Yes, it is correct. For the comparison, I picked the smallest *integer* $k$ that does the job, for no special reason. For sure we want to use a $k\gt 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am formalizing the comments:

$$\Gamma(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^{a-1}\text{ d}y$$

$$\Gamma(a+1)=\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^a\text{ d}y$$

Convergence:

So we know that $\Gamma(x)$ converges (for at least $x\geqslant0$)

because it converges significantly faster than $x^{-2}$ for arbitrarily large $x$ values.